# Best way to model Android REST connection

Tags: java, android, json, rest

I am making an Android app that connects to a web service via REST API and I have a dilemma with the design of the internal architecture.

Now I have class Client.java whose purpouse is make connect with the server (ConnectionMethod is Enum that contains GET|POST values):

```
public class Client {
private AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(); //I use com.loopj.AsyncHttpClient to connect
private ConnectionMethod method;
private RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
private AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler = new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
        //Actions when connection success
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response, Throwable error) {
        //Actions when connection fails
    }
};

public Client (RequestParams params, ConnectionMethod method) {
    this.params = params;
    this.method = method;
}

public void addParameters (Map<String, String> parameters) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
        this.params.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}

public ServerResponse connect () {
    RequestHandle handle;

    if (this.method==ConnectionMethod.POST) {
        handle = postRequest();
    }
    else {
        handle = getRequest();
    }
    //How can I treat here different type of responses homogeneously?
}

private RequestHandle getRequest () {
    return client.get(Constants.getEndpoint(), this.params, this.responseHandler);
}

private RequestHandle postRequest () {
    return client.post(Constants.getEndpoint(), this.params, this.responseHandler);
}
}
```

A sample method that requests info from the server is this:

```
public static void login (String login, String password) {
//This classes should be static or dynamic?
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("login", login);
    map.put("password", password);
    map.put("method", "site_login");

    Client c = new Client();
    c.addParameters(map);
    c.getRequest();
}
```

All server responses are JSON: {status:0, result:array/int/string} when response is correct and {status:-1, message:string} when response is incorrect.

Additionaly I want to make classes to model components from JSON result (User.java, Message.java...) and intermediate methods between UI and API to implement the logic of the app and classes.

What is the best way to design an homogeneous connection system that manages automatically correct/fail response and independent of model (user, message...)?

Comment: Don't bother, use Retrofit http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing tools that already exist. My favorite happens to be [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) but there are others out there. Retrofit can handle the success and fail responses and even map JSON directly to a POJO.

My API client

```
public class ApiClient {

private static ApiInterface sApiInterface;

public static ApiInterface getApiClient(Context context) {

    //build the rest adapter
    if (sApiInterface == null) {
        final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint("example.com")
                .build();
        sApiInterface = restAdapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }
    return sApiInterface;
}


public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("/program/{id}")
    void getProgram(@Path("id") int id, RetrofitCallback<Program> callback);

}
```

My RetrofitCallback

```
public class RetrofitCallback<S> implements Callback<S> {
private static final String TAG = RetrofitCallback.class.getSimpleName();


@Override
public void success(S s, Response response) {

}

@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to make http request for: " + error.getUrl());
    Response errorResponse = error.getResponse();
    if (errorResponse != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, errorResponse.getReason());
        if (errorResponse.getStatus() == 500) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Handle Server Errors Here");
        }
    }
}
}
```

My model

```
public class Program {
@Expose
private doublea.models.Airtime Airtime;
@Expose
private String id;
@Expose
private String title;
@SerializedName("short_name")
@Expose
private String shortName;
@SerializedName("full_description")
@Expose
private String fullDescription;
@SerializedName("short_description")
@Expose
private String shortDescription;
@Expose
private doublea.models.Image Image;
@SerializedName("image")
@Expose
private String imageName;
@Expose
private List<Host> hosts = new ArrayList<Host>();
@Expose
private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
@Expose
private List<Airtime> airtimes = new ArrayList<Airtime>();

/** Getters and Setters */

public Program() {
}
```

How it is used.

```
private void executeProgramApiCall(int programId) {
    ApiClient.getApiClient(this).getProgram(programId, new RetrofitCallback<Program>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Program program, Response response) {
            super.success(program, response);
            addDataToAdapter(program);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a bunch of frameworks which can make this whole process much easier.
For example `Retrofit` is very simple framework for mapping java classes to REST calls. It comes with `gson` which will automatically deserialize response from json to plain java objects.

It also allows use callbacks as well as rxJava Observables. It allows to handle errors as well.

You can check sample app: https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020